# Neural network to predict Y = x1*x2*x3

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, regression

My training data consists of 3 variables `X1`, `X2`, `X3` such that

```
Y = (X1 * X2 / 1e6) * X3
```

Example of data

| X1 | X2 | X3 | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 310 | 768 | 952 | 0.2267 |
| 157 | 889 | 860 | 0.1200 |
| 157 | 787 | 610 | 0.0754 |
| 97 | 385 | 118 | 0.044 |

using data size of 80000 rows trained over 500 epochs with early stopping.

I structured the network like so

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
```

However, after training the output network were unable to predict even seen training examples.

Training loss stalled at about 0.0145

```
model.predict([
    [310, 768, 952], 
    [157,787,610],
    [1,1,1],
    [5,5,5]
])

# output:
# array([[0.07321107],
#       [0.07321107],
#       [0.07321107],
#       [0.07321107]], dtype=float32)
```

Which is wrong. Wondering what should I do to correct this?

Comment: Have you tried smaller learning rate (particularly if and when the loss plateaus)?

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: seems like the model didn't learn much. are you sure you aren't stopping too early ?

Comment: I tried removing early stop callback, seems to have no impact on loss. Though, reducing learning rate seems to have good effect. It gives output that is closer to expected output.

Comment: The next to try is to **add more neurons to the hidden layers**. In the meantime, I want to still emphasize the importance of having a **sufficiently small learning rate** and **monitoring the loss-vs-epoch variations**.

Comment: Related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/47787/64377 (check the most upvoted answer).

Comment: Tried changing neuron count to 64 --> 1024 --> 1. Seems okay. But whats good rule of thumb for number of nueurons.